# Paypal Express Checkout: Apply order discount

Tags: c#, paypal

Have an ecommerce site running ZNode. We send tax, shipping, order total, etc. Everything works fine until an order level discount is applied (say 50%). We get a response from PayPal that says the following:

The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.

I'm traversing the API, and I can't find anything to apply an order level discount. FWIW, the user is applying discount codes on our site, and then is being transferred to PayPal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think your problem is not the PayPal API.
You checked that everything works perfect with your parameters passed to paypal in this 50% discount case?

After the PayPal Documentation you should provide a negative value to reflect a discount on an order. So everything adds up to the total amount.

Source: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECCustomizing

[image]

**Update with code: (by Nick)**

I have a paypal service that does all kinds of stuff, but the following code should give you an idea of how the discount works. The discount is not a special type, it's a product just like any other except it's disguised by naming it like a discount and setting it's price to a negative number.

```
            List<PaymentDetailsItemType> items = paymentDetails.PaymentDetailsItem;

        foreach (ShoppingCartItem item in cart.ShoppingCartItems)
        {
            items.Add(new PaymentDetailsItemType
                          {
                              Name = item.Book.Title,
                              Quantity = item.Quantity,
                              Number = item.BookId.ToString(),
                              Amount =
                                  new BasicAmountType
                                      {currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.USD, 
                                       value = (item.Book.Price).To2Places()}
                          });
        }
        if (cartTotals.Discount > 0)
        {
            items.Add(new PaymentDetailsItemType
                          {
                              Name = "Promo Code Discount",
                              Quantity = 1,
                              Number = "PromoCode",
                              Amount =
                                  new BasicAmountType
                                      {
                                          currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.USD,
                                          value = (cartTotals.Discount*-1).To2Places()
                                      }
                          });
        }
```

Comment: I've set TaxTotal, ShippingTotal, ItemTotal, and OrderTotal. These all work except when a discount code is set, as the item + shipping + tax won't add up to the OrderTotal since the OrderTotal has an amount taken off of it. There's nowhere that I can find to set a discount amount. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that I need to create an item and set the value to negative? And then update the ItemTotal to reflect all items as well as the negative item that I added to account for the discount?

Comment: @look yes that - look at the documentation - I am not the only one who can read that thing :)

Comment: Gotta be a quirk on how I'm implementing this, then. I read that documentation earlier, and still am getting this message. Will debug a bit further and post the code I'm using....thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: The PayPal 'Customizing' documentation mentions "You may provide a negative value to reflect a discount on an order, for example." in the description of the `Amount` field for order details, but nowhere else. @Skomski – I can read, but I missed that info because I didn't think including discounts would be considered 'customizing' PayPal checkout. Also, the documentation for both the `SetExpressCheckout` and `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` operations does not include that info in the description of the same field.

Comment: @LookitsPuck I added an example image.

Comment: @Skomski - this answer is incomplete - please provide the actual html form markup (e.g. for a standard paypal button) that works for you, showing that you used a negative number. I agree with Kenny Evitt I looked at the doc you mentioned and all that doc says is to use a negative value e.g. -5.00 but gives no example of real html form markup, e.g. for a paypal button. Moreover, when I tried using a negative value for a discount, I got: "The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount." from paypal when clicking the paypal buy button.

Comment: @Nick - thanks for the image but can you show the actual "behind the scenes" coding to make this discount possible? e.g. for a paypal button, what would the html form markup look like? Here is a possible solution: https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_cart_upload - see section "Setting Discounts For the cart" - it provides specific form field elements to use for discount - did you use this, Nick? Another, similar doc is https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_howto_checkout_outside#methodtwo but this does not discuss discount at all

Comment: @therobyouknow I didn't use a form field for the discount, that would be dangerous #1, and #2 it doesn't need to be on the UI, this is all handled server side. I query my promo code service, determine the discount and then send paypal essentially another product, but it's named promo code with a negative amount. I'll update with code..

Comment: @Nick +1 upvote both your follow up comments - thank you very much for following up and the advice - yes I agree and also thank you for the code in the answer - I've upvoted that too. I will certainly look into your approach as an alternative to the form based discount one. Thankyou!

Comment: @therobyouknow No problem. I say don't use the form based solution as you originally got the discount server side, sent it to the client, and then the client sent it to you. And because what if they modify the form field? Might as well skip all of that. The code I provided is for a discount on the entire cart but this same logic could be extended to do a discount per item by just adding more discount items.

Comment: +1 thanks @Nick for your further input. I certainly agree that a reasonably tech-savvy buyer can modify the form field to make a bigger discount and pay less. The seller could manually check the correct discounts and amounts and this may suit small sellers if there is only development resource to provide such a simpler solution but it is labour intensive for the sellet to have to check. Better solution (which I think yours is about) is to make it impossible for a tech-savvy buyer to intercept the payment data. So yes, thanks again for your input about this.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for sending a discount via the PayPal API use the `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPDISCAMT`

Which is actually a shipping discount, but works just fine, and is a one line.

But it does say shipping discount at the PalPal end.

Answer (score 0):

Add the discount value to the PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT parameter and it will works fine.

In other words, if you consider your discount as a product, passing it through L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME(i), L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT(i) and L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY(i), then you have to sum the discount value to the products value and pass the result into the PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT param.