# PayPal Express Apply Discount to ItemTotal/SubTotal

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

[PayPalExpress version 95.0](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index#expresscheckoutnew) ASP.Net & C#

```
CurrencyCodeType currency = (CurrencyCodeType)
   Enum.Parse(typeof(CurrencyCodeType), currencyCode.SelectedValue);
PaymentDetailsType paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
paymentDetails.ShippingTotal = new BasicAmountType(currency, shippingTotal.Value);
paymentDetails.ItemTotal = new BasicAmountType(currency, itemTotal.ToString());
paymentDetails.OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType(currency, orderTotal.ToString());
```

I only see `ShippingDiscount`. I'm wondering ***how to apply Discount*** on `ItemTotal`/SubTotal (not on individual item).

[image]

I found [Paypal Express Checkout: Apply order discount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002971/paypal-express-checkout-apply-order-discount) in SO but the answer was about individual item discount.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG! Just figured this out! It was right in that you have to add another item to your items as a discount. The hard part was getting the sub/total(s) correct!

Here's my `SUCCESS` submit:

```
array(14) {
    //  ERROR AREA 1    //  Total Amount of Items (including -Discount) and shipping and tax
    ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"]
            =>  string(4) "9.71"
    //  ERROR AREA 2    //  Total Amount of items ONLY, including the -Discount!
    ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"]
            =>  string(4) "6.76"
    ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT"]
            =>  string(4) "2.95"
    ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT"]
            =>  string(1) "0"

    /*  ITEMS   */

        /*  ITEM 01 */
    ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"]
            =>  string(18) "Order # 987654"
    ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0"]
            =>  float(12.51)
    ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0"]
            =>  string(6) "987654"
    ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0"]
            =>  float(1)
    ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0"]
            =>  string(8) "Physical"

        /*  ITEM 02 */
        /*  ¡THE DISCOUNT!  */
    ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1"]
            =>  string(9) "PromoCode"
    ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1"]
            =>  float(-5.75)
    ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1"]
            =>  string(18) "Promo 123456"
    ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1"]
            =>  float(1)
    ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY1"]
            =>  string(8) "Physical"
}
```

### ***SUCCESS!***

```
array(6) {
    ["TOKEN"]
        =>  string(20) "NOTIMPORTANT"
    ["TIMESTAMP"]
        =>  string(20) "2014-10-03T12:39:06Z"
    ["CORRELATIONID"]
        =>  string(12) "NOTIMPORTANT"
    ["ACK"]
        =>  string(7) "SUCCESS"
    ["VERSION"]
        =>  string(2) "93"
    ["BUILD"]
        =>  string(8) "13154493"
}
```

---

> And yes, I know this question is old, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere else that worked. So here's my working solution!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Currently, I could not verify it using C#. I'll mark it as Accepted Answer for now. Once I get a chance to test it, I'll come back and comment again.