# Is it possible to use Paypal Express Checkout without sending the whole order details?

Tags: paypal

I have experienced a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7002971/759866), while trying to make my discounts work with `SetExpressCheckout`.

I've resolved to use the method the accepted answer's author suggests: creating an additional product named "discount" with a negative value.

This is not too bad, but I'm getting fed up to have to accommodate Paypal with all the changes I make on my cart, and basically send the whole cart to Amazon when the customer has already had plenty of opportunities to check it while on my website and he now just wants to pay.

I would prefer to send the customer to a blank Paypal payment page, without the cart on the left.

Is this possible with Paypal Express Checkout? Any alternative?

Comment: But in short you don't want to show user cart on a left how user will pay then?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit Exactly!

Comment: is @anant dabhi's answer helpful to you?

Comment: and by the way why you want this facility indeed?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit See my comment under Anant's answer, it doesn't help I'm afraid, so yes the real question is: is it possible *not* to send the cart on the left, and how?

Comment: But my straight question is to you is you want to give discount to customer but don't want to show right? is this then why don't to change original price?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit Forget about the discount, it was just an introduction to the real problem. I have no real problem sending the discount, my problem is that any time I make the slightest change to our cart system, it breaks Paypal, and I have to do extra work over there. Hence my question: is it possible to only send the amount the customer has to pay, with no extra information?

Comment: So paypal.com is sending invoice to your customer with extra information right?

Answer (score 0):

If you go thru **Paypal Express Checkout** then it possible to give discount

[image]

(1) – Item name. The item name can identify this item to distinguish it from other line items in the order.

(2) – Item description. This field identifies which of several items the buyer is purchasing. For example, you may be offering an item in different sizes. Knowing the size helps the buyer decide whether the one they selected was appropriate. If the item is an eBay auction item, it is recommended that you provide the phrase "eBay item" in this field.

(3) – Item number. Each item can be further identified by an item number. If the item is an eBay auction item, it is recommended that you provide the eBay item number in this field.

(4) – Item unit price. This field specifies exactly how much one unit of the item costs. It can be a positive or negative value but not zero.

(5) – Item unit quantity. This field identifies the number of units the buyer is ordering. PayPal calculates the value in the Amount (6) column as the product of line-item unit price and line-item unit quantity. You can also show other detailed information about the order:

(7) – Item total and tax, which are the total of all items in the order and the tax, respectively.

(8) – Shipping and handling, which is the sum of the shipping and handling amounts.

Note: You must determine actual shipping and handling amounts.
(9) – Shipping discount. If the buyer is receiving a discount on shipping, the value appears as a credit in this field.

(10) – Insurance. This field shows the insurance fee when there is insurance on shipping.

(11) – Total. This is the total of the order, including shipping, handling, tax, and other price adjustment-related items.

visit the link ...to get more info https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/

Comment: You're answering the wrong question I'm afraid, the open question is "is it possible to skip sending the cart entirely". Now to react to your answer, I know about this *shipping discount* field, but its name is confusing for the customer, because it's only on the shipping. What if your discount exceeds the shipping fee?

Comment: Then you should go with paypal pro.. its give you many option so far .. but its not free..

Comment: I am using Paypal Pro already, to accept credit cards using their API. But I cannot find any difference with Pro as regards to this payment page. Any link?

Answer (score 0):

NO, you can not send to the customer to a blank Paypal payment page, without the cart on the left. Because you can not say: I'm not selling anything and give me your money.
But alternative, you can do this way:
Change your coffee = $200 instead of $20 for total prize. And you don't need to list anything else after.

Comment: "*Because you can not say: I'm not selling anything and give me your money.*" That's what most payment solutions do, the user completes the checkout on your website, and the payment gateway just takes the cash, you don't have to explain what it's for. Plus, when using Paypal Pro to accept credit cards with the Paypal API, funnily enough Paypal doesn't ask more than the price to pay.